# Eric Angelini's "1995" puzzle

Tags: code-golf, sequence

The following puzzle was invented by Eric Angelini in September 2007.

As mentioned in [A131744](https://oeis.org/A131744) :

> the sequence is defined by the property that if one writes the English
> names for the entries, replaces each letter with its rank in the
> alphabet and calculates the absolute values of the differences, one
> recovers the sequence.

To be precise, the alphabet starts at 1, so a is 1, b is 2, etc.
Also, 15 is supposed to be treated as fifteen and 21 as twentyone (not twenty-one).

### Example :

Begin with 1 :

```
1 -> "one" -> 15,14,5 -> absolute(15-14),absolute(14-5) -> 1,9
1,9 -> "one,nine" -> 15,14,5,14,9,14,5 -> 1,9,9,5,5,9
1,9,9,5,5,9 -> "one,nine,nine,five,five,nine" -> 15,14,5,14,9,14,5,14,9,14,5,6,9,22,5,6,9,22,5,14,9,14,5 -> 1,9,9,5,5,9,9,5,5,9,1,3,13,17,1,3,13,17,9,5,5,9
1,9,9,5,5,9,9,5,5,9,1,3,13,17,1,3,13,17,9,5,5,9 -> ...
```

So the first 22 terms are : `1,9,9,5,5,9,9,5,5,9,1,3,13,17,1,3,13,17,9,5,5,9`

You can find the 40000 first terms here : [b131744](https://oeis.org/A131744/b131744.txt)

### Challenge

Sequence I/O methods apply. You may use one of the following I/O methods:

- Take no input and output the sequence indefinitely,
- Take a (0- or    1-based) index i and output the i-th term,
- Take a non-negative    integer i and output the first i terms.

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Is `15` supposed to be treated as `one five` or `fifteen`?

Comment: And would `42` be `forty-two`, `forty two`, `fortytwo`, `four two`, or `fourtwo`? I assume it's either `fortytwo` or `fourtwo`.

Comment: 15 is fifteen and 42 is fortytwo. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 119 bytes

Outputs the sequence indefinitely.

```python
from unicodedata import*
p,*a=b'5NE'
for x in a:
 if x>45:n=abs(p-x);a+=name(chr(13144+n))[38:print(n%24)].encode();p=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc0xDsIgFADQnVP8xRRaNanQxNDg5uoFjMNvCykDH4KY4Okxvgu89C17JNmayzHAh/waN7thQfAhxVx6lo49mqWbHveOuZihgidAzcA7qDc1aTK4vHk6VTHjYAiD5eue@ShHpQYS4imvOmVPhdPhosTrbOmfcDEnU1v7AQ)

Python's `unicodedata.name` allows us to access the name of a unicode character. It happens that the characters with codepoints in the range `0x3358..0x336D` partially contain all of the required words (as can be seen in [this](https://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt) list). The only nuance is at `twentyone`, of which `name()` gives us `twenty-one` instead. This is fixed with a simple `if x>45`, which ignores any existing `-`. This allows us to save over 70 bytes in total. Other than the sneaky `unicodedata.name`, it is essentially the same as the answer below.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 196 bytes

```python
p,*a=b'Wne'
for x in a:n=abs(x-p);print(n%22);p=x;a+=b'zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thir,four,fif,,seven,eigh,,,twentyone,,'.split(b',')[n]+b'teen'*(12<n<20)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsIwEETvfkUvkrRdRePNtt/hQTwksLWBsgnJ2qb@fGwFwdvM8B7jFx4cXXL2UOnOiBuh2PUuFKmwVOgrddpEmQ6@bHywxJL2Sq25S42uV/6NwYEjBJ4d8BAQoXevAL2dEKJNEHFCArTPgYHsBm51/K4847hiPNjws3r4MwA2hHjZDkAcox8tSyNAlHd61EYwIolKnlVLrTqVOX8A)

#### Explanation

We start off with `a = b'ne'`, which will keep track of all the English words.
Note that `ne` are the last two letters of `one` (the first number in the sequence). In the following for loop, we iterate over `a`, and in each iteration we add a word to the sequence based on the value of `abs(x-p)`, where `x` and `p` are the current and previous letters in `a`, respectively.

The illustration below, while not an exact model, roughly describes the algorithm I am using to construct the sequence:

```python
'one',             n = abs(s[2]-s[1]) = abs('e'-'n') = 9 ->
'onenine',         n = abs(s[3]-s[2]) = abs('n'-'e') = 9 ->
'oneninenine',     n = abs(s[4]-s[3]) = abs('i'-'n') = 5 ->
'onenineninefive', n = abs(s[5]-s[4]) = abs('n'-'i') = 5 ->
...
```

One last thing to mention is the peculiar `W` in the initialization of `a`, or the strange `%22` within the `print` statement. These are both needed to print the initial `1`. We may get rid of them for **[190 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsIwEETvfkVvSdtVtN5s@yXiIYGNDZRNSNY29edjKgjeZob3GL/x5Oias4dGjVoQioNxoUqVpUrdaFQ6ynT0de@DJZZUwph61Rb2jcGBIwReHfAUEMG4VwBjF4RoE0RckADtc2Igu4N7nb8rrzgXjCcbfpaBPwNgR4i3ciBO0c@WpRYg6js9Wi0YkUQjL91AQ3euc/4A)**, but the `1` at the beginning would be omitted:

```python
p,*a=b'ne'
for x in a:n=abs(x-p);print(n);p=x;a+=b'zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thir,four,fif,,seven,eigh,,,twentyone'.split(b',')[n]+b'teen'*(12<n<20)
```

This is currently the shortest fix I could find for eliminating this edge case, though there's likely a shorter approach (I'll exclude an explanation for it as an exercise to the reader).

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>240</s>  228 bytes

*Thanks to @ovs for pointing out that 16, 19 and 20 are never used*

A naive implementation. Returns the \$n\$<sup>th</sup> term, 0-indexed.

```javascript
f=(n,a=[1])=>1/a[n]?a[n]:f(n,[...Buffer(a.map(x=>`ZeroOneTwoThreeFourFiveSixSevenEightNineTenElevenTwelveThirteenFourteenFifteenXSeventeenEighteenXXTwentyone`.match(/.[a-z]*/g)[x]).join``)].map(x=>Math.abs(a-(a=x&31))).slice(1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZDBasMwEETv@QodQpGaWo7JralSKDS3tof4EGoMUt2VreCuguw4bo2/3ZUMuew8hhl22ZPqVFM4c24jtN8wTVpQfFAiS3ImdkmsMsyfw3jU3s845y8XrcFRxX/UmfZiJz/B2Q@E9GrTygHs7cXtTQcH0x@gA3w1ZdW@Gx/wXAcnvULdQVoZ1wJgyM9qdJDjXAo0F4Nz9AVsfy2C9EvboqIxz1T0l9/HJcv6nPGTNSgly283vam24uqroSqiSvR3m4QxxpvaFEA9Tto6ikSQ9ZYgeSKbdYDVipFhQUhhsbE18NqWVCq6HHBkPrsc/AfYKNl2MU7/)

Comment: According to the OEIS entry 16, 19 and 20 never appear in the sequence. That should help to save some bytes

Comment: Scratch that, @Arnauld; I was going by the sequence as it appears in the spec and on OEIS - checked the full list since and see I was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>69</s> 64 bytes

```
ị“£3ṃ×ʋƁṘFqœ<ɦẎĠ_NɗṾDæ¢$⁽ċ¶Ọɦµ⁽ƭẈġȥ⁶J§GaĊƙ-ƬėƓjḢƥ4¶;»Ḳ¤FOạƝ
1Ç¡ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AYcAeP9qZWxsef//4buL4oCcwqMz4bmDw5fKi8aB4bmYRnHFkzzJpuG6jsSgX07Jl@G5vkTDpsKiJOKBvcSLwrbhu4zJpsK14oG9xq3huojEocil4oG2SsKnR2HEisaZLcasxJfGk2rhuKLGpTTCtjvCu@G4ssKkRk/huqHGnQoxw4fCoeG4o////zc)

A pair of links that is called as a monad with an integer input \$n\$ and returns the first \$n\$ terms. Slow for larger n (since it actually generates far more terms than needed before truncating the list). At a cost of a byte, [this](https://tio.run/##AYsAdP9qZWxsef//4buL4oCcwqMz4bmDw5fKi8aB4bmYRnHFkzzJpuG6jsSgX07Jl@G5vkTDpsKiJOKBvcSLwrbhu4zJpsK14oG9xq3huojEocil4oG2SsKnR2HEisaZLcasxJfGk2rhuKLGpTTCtjvCu@G4ssKkRk/huqHGneG4owoxw6fGrOG5qv///zMw) is much more efficient.

Thanks to @JonathanAllan for saving 5 bytes!

### Explanation

#### Helper link

```
ị                | Index into:
 “£…;»Ḳ¤         | - "one two three four … twentyone zero", split on spaces
        F        | Flatten
         ØaiⱮ    | Index of each character in the lowercase alphabet
             ạƝ  | Absolute differences of neighbouring pairs
```

#### Main link

```
1                | Starting with 1:
 Ç¡              | Call the helper link n times
   ḣ             | First n values
```

Comment: `ØaiⱮ` can just be `O` since the differences will still be the same.

Comment: Is `twentyone` too far along? I think so [TIO](https://tio.run/##AWwAk/9qZWxsef//4oCcwqRAfWbCtlXDsSvDhOKBuMOeWsWTc2R64bqgxp3GkWbGmDLCs@G7jeKBvsOQROG5m8il4buNwr10MnjKoGI3xpMx4bmYwq5uxKEwa1Phu4s0TT7CtjvCu@G4sjIz4buL//8)

Comment: This is right I think, and saves two in the process [TIO](https://tio.run/##AYcAeP9qZWxsef//4buL4oCcwqMz4bmDw5fKi8aB4bmYRnHFkzzJpuG6jsSgX07Jl@G5vkTDpsKiJOKBvcSLwrbhu4zJpsK14oG9xq3huojEocil4oG2SsKnR2HEisaZLcasxJfGk2rhuKLGpTTCtjvCu@G4ssKkRk/huqHGnQoxw4fCoeG4o////zc)

Comment: (The first difference would be at the 1117th entry.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 117 bytes

outputs the first i terms

```
(s=#;NestWhile[Abs@Differences@Flatten[LetterNumber[Characters@IntegerName@#/."-"->""]&/@#]&,{1},Tr[1^#]<s&][[;;s]])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnRCoIwFIDhd9lgFGjqtRmTIghCCoIuxgmmHHXgdrFzvIqefXn18/F7yzN6y26waWqeq0PWaUeNrDskfs9uQdP2pC9uHDFiGJD0dbHMGMwdt8Ru9T1Gc55ttMNm0rfAOG3DetSyOIhc5CchQBVagsq@1S97RVN9JBxJgTF1TQB7lR7RBdaTqcoSUvoD)

Comment: Mind adding an explanation?  I'm learning Wolfram and while I understand most of this, a few parts are still foreign.

Comment: In case you're interested, there's a 90-byte implementation by Giorgos Kalogeropoulos (`Nest[Abs@Differences@Flatten[LetterNumber[Characters[IntegerName@#]/."-"->""]&/@#]&,{1},4]`) on the linked OEIS page (https://oeis.org/A131744).

Comment: @Jonah This simply produces nested chunks of terms until the desired number of terms is reached and then takes only the first i terms.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 83 bytes

```
1 9"£{`λḭ ƛ» ∧ḭ ⟇¯ ×² ß• ⌐≤ ƈḞ ∵‹ ¢Ṗ Ẇ„ ⟨ǐ t¥ẏ⟑⌈ ⟇¯⟑⌈ Ṡ□ ⌐≤⟑⌈ e⋏ṫ⟑⌈ ←⊍λḭ`⌈¥‹İṅC¯ȧ…£
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=1%209%22%C2%A3%7B%60%CE%BB%E1%B8%AD%20%C6%9B%C2%BB%20%E2%88%A7%E1%B8%AD%20%E2%9F%87%C2%AF%20%C3%97%C2%B2%20%C3%9F%E2%80%A2%20%E2%8C%90%E2%89%A4%20%C6%88%E1%B8%9E%20%E2%88%B5%E2%80%B9%20%C2%A2%E1%B9%96%20%E1%BA%86%E2%80%9E%20%E2%9F%A8%C7%90%20t%C2%A5%E1%BA%8F%E2%9F%91%E2%8C%88%20%E2%9F%87%C2%AF%E2%9F%91%E2%8C%88%20%E1%B9%A0%E2%96%A1%20%E2%8C%90%E2%89%A4%E2%9F%91%E2%8C%88%20e%E2%8B%8F%E1%B9%AB%E2%9F%91%E2%8C%88%20%E2%86%90%E2%8A%8D%CE%BB%E1%B8%AD%60%E2%8C%88%C2%A5%E2%80%B9%C4%B0%E1%B9%85C%C2%AF%C8%A7%E2%80%A6%C2%A3&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Outputs the values infinitely

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.text.english`, <sup><s>109</s></sup> 98 bytes

```
[ { 1 } [ [ number>text R/ \sand|,|-| / ""re-replace >array ] map-flat differences vabs ] repeat ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU67TsNAEOzzFaPU2BGiAyktoqEAUYUUm8vYWXE@n/Y2UQLm280F0HTz7iT4aPPb69Pz4z3ETC4Fg/ihdZ69ZeqjlsMfU1xci2v4d5x4zRYYe54zstH9kk2T44OWGNEz0STqZw2OqSCMQ9ZIa4@uUV1Z8LBY3M0bfOEW39hUpOOwo62v83hZ4b1I2k83UzNhheXS2BhzlECsf99iW8/kpovi2GvX0ZhC7T3JrlStmlmV7RwkRrTzDw)

Takes a 0-based index and outputs the i-th term.

- `{ 1 } [ ... ] repeat` Call a quotation a given number of times, transforming our starting sequence `{ 1 }` that many times.
- `[ ... ] map-flat` Apply a quotation to each element of a sequence, collecting each result into a flat sequence.
- `number>text` Convert a number to a string, like `2222 -> "two thousand, two hundred and twenty-two"`.
- `R/ \sand|,|-| / ""re-replace` Since number>text produces commas, spaces, hyphens and `" and"`, strip them out with a regular expression.
- `>array` Convert the string to an array (e.g. `"hi" -> { 104 105 }`). This is necessary for `differences` to work properly.
- `differences` Take the first-order forward difference.
- `vabs` Take the absolute value of a sequence. (Like `[ abs ] map`, but shorter).